# Why do some assemblies have to be loaded from the Assembly Manager and others can simply be added through NuGet?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-assembly

Why do some assemblies have to be loaded from the Assembly Manager and others can simply be added through NuGet?

For example, I have to manually add System.Data when using certain NuGet packages, like Deedle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the person who made the NuGet package was lazy and did not include the framework dependencies in the nuspec file.

If you unzip the .nupkg file and look inside the .nuspc file it should contain a

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
    <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

inside of it to have System.Data automatically included. I double checked the nuspec file bundled with the [Deedle package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Deedle/), it did not conain it. You should file a bug report with Deedle saying it needs to be included if it is needed for their software to run.